# Guidelines while using: ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads and ThreadPool.SetMinThreads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

In one of my applications, I have to use multiple threads.
As a better approach, I have replaced a thread queue by `ThreadPool`.

At start of Form, I set Min/Max Threads as follows:

```
  ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(20,20)
  ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1,1)
```

Later on while using, I use `ThreadPool` as follow:

```
 Function()
 {
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Action), arguments); 
 }
```

I am not using any sort of `DeQueue`.

It will be help full if some one can share their experience with `ThreadPool` (specially Set MIN/MAX interfaces)

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: What is the version of C# you use ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's not recommended to change the thread pool size. From MSDN:

> Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread
> pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse
> effect on code libraries you use.
>
> If the common language runtime is hosted, for example by Internet
> Information Services (IIS) or SQL Server, the host can limit or
> prevent changes to the thread pool size.

The CLR or the host (e.g. IIS) on its own will determine whether to increase or decrease the thread pool size based on the threading patterns of your application so if I were you, I wouldn't bother playing with these numbers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Volpav,Thanks for information. Continueing query:  If I know my application might have burst of around 20 threads running at the same time, will it not be risky to keep Thread pool size as default. Here Program which will be running is the general user program. So I doubt it may change thread pool automatically.  Can you suggest?

Comment: @SachinD I understand your concerns, but I still think that in your case there's nothing to worry about. IIS6 had default thread pool size of 20 threads _per CPU_ (meaning that if you have multi-core/multi-processor hardware, the limit is even higher). I'm not sure, but I think with IIS7 this number went up to about 50 threads. Also, do you have an actual problem that you're solving with thread pool size increase? We all know that premature optimizations are the root of all evil ;-) Cheers!

Comment: Hello Volpav, thanks for information. Finally I have decided to have use default thread pool size and not to over write it. My problem has been solved. The reason to look into thread pool was: I had memory leaks in my existing code( Thread's queue managed in source code itself). After thread pool there is no memory leak seen.

Comment: @SachinD Glad you figured it out :-) Cheers!