# Thread starvation issue

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core

I have NopCommerce 4.0 website in production. This site is written in net 4.6.1 and AspNetCore 2.0. From the beginning i've noticed that under low load the site become unresponsive: max 30 clicks/s, response time 2-3 s and cpu load max 20%. It was a disaster. After heavy caching of hot paths I've managed to jump to 50 clicks/sec, response time < 1s, CPU load 25%. That's all.

After I've studied a lot the issue I concluded that is a classic thread starvation issue. The threads count stays at 50 despite the load. I've studied the code and thats's my observations:

- the application use AspNetCore 2.0 but the path code from controller actions down to the DB or IO calls are sync. All services, components and factories are not written async. I installed a tool to capture the blocking threads and indeed: there are tons of blocking calls to:

  - db calls
  - redis call
  - razor load of cshtml pages

All these calls are blocking because the code is not async.

Now, I have two options:

1. Rewrite all the code in order to be full async. This is not a valid option because I'm using plenty of third party view components plugins, for which I don't have the source code. They are also not async written as I sow with Net Reflector.
2. Increase the number of threads in ThreadPool in order to compensate the blocked threads. This option looks great as a quick workaround but it doesn't work. Everything I've tried to increase the number of treads had no effect. The following code in Program.cs has no effect to process ThreadPool:
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ComPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMaxWorkerThreads", "10000");
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ComPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMinWorkerThreads", "8000");
   System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10000, 100);
   System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(8000, 100);
   The runtime threads count stays steady at 50 and the website become quickly unresponsive.

As a last-change option I implemented a webgarden with max 4 worker processes with in-memory cache data cloned and sync via Redis. This is not a solution because of huge memory use (each process has a clone of cached memory - reading/writing from/to Redis at runtime is excluded because of huge performance penalties)

How to increase the number of threads? Nothing I tried seems to work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This may be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699392/guidelines-while-using-threadpool-setmaxthreads-and-threadpool-setminthreads-in

Comment: Thank you. I've tested to change Machine.config for net framework. Nothing. The Nop.Web.exe has only 50 threads and is unresponsive under low load. It would be a quick fix if i could increase the threads number. it seams that IIS + AspCore ignore any settings. It use ThreadPool as all the program is written async.